# How to remove Author and Category from a single portfolio page?

Tags: css

I have a little issue with removing the Category and Author from my single portfolio pages. I tried different suggestions from other posts here and nothing worked, I also tried to modify the code myself and am hitting a wall again. Apparently it seems the right code to be added is strictly individual depending on the page and I was hoping someone can give me a little nudge. I'am using the Edge theme and there's the link to one of the pages that I'm trying to work on:

https://etc-fos4panel-prd.azurewebsites.net/?portfolio-item=wireless-control

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

if not remove by code and other setting then try to hide it by using the css,
Use body class so it will not affect on other single pages

```
.single-portfolio .author, .single-portfolio .cat-links{display:none}
or 
.single-portfolio-item .author, .single-portfolio-item .cat-links{display:none}
```